# Position span item to wrap block of text

Tags: html, css

I am having a small problem trying to get some quotations to stick to my content and wrap correctly but struggling with the positioning.

So here is a demo: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d0zap25q/)

Now there be an argument as to why I am not using the  mwethod, I found this REALLY erratic and this seemed like a simpler solution.

```
.blockquote1 {
    color: #009FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.quoteLeft{
    color: #009FFF;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-180deg);         
}

.quoteRight{
    color: #009FFF;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
}

<span class="quoteLeft">"</span><span class="blockquote1">Mark  designed and produced our website for us by using the photos that I supplied him with and his own ingenuity. I am not the best photographer but mark used his magic hand to make them look as though they were professionally taken. Mark spent a great deal of time on the website to make sure that it looked professional and …would not make the website live until I was completely happy, I would recommend him to anyone wanting a well presented website.</span><span class="quoteRight">"</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue myself just added position absolute to the second blockquote and some margin:

```
.quoteRight{
    color: #009FFF;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Would have been better to just add `vertical-align:top` to quoteRight

Comment: Let me give that a whirl it would sure look neater.

Comment: seems to work fine for me in ff, chrome and ie11 - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/d0zap25q/1/